# "no such file or directory" in python with PIL and tkinter module

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to display an image in a tkinter window but I keep getting the error "No such file or directory".
I tried two methods but both are returning an error.

```
import tkinter 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import os 
root = tkinter.Tk() 
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C\Users\masee\OneDrive\Desktop\csc project with image\expensifypic.png")) 
panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = img) 
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes") 
root.mainloop()
```

And this is the second try:

```
import tkinter 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import os 
root = tkinter.Tk() 
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage("expensifypic.png")) 
panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = img) 
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes") 
root.mainloop()
```

I am new to tkinter and PIL modules so please help me out.

Comment: On the first one (the long path) you forgot ':' after the 'C' you need to write it like this:
C:\Users\masee\OneDrive\Desktop\csc project with image\expensifypic.png  
because it is a drive.

Comment: I think you should use double backslash in path provided, like this `c:\\users\\masae\\...`. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign the image directly, see below, the code is commented.

I've even import Path from pathlib.

```
import tkinter 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import os
from pathlib import Path

root = tkinter.Tk()

#assume the pic is in the same directory
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pngegg.png")

#get image
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    image = Image.open(Path(filename))
    #resize it
    image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #notice this
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    #ready to show...
    panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = img) 
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
else:
    print("filename {0} is not the right file".format(filename))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: It is valid to use `filename` in `Image.open()`, calling `Path()` on `filename` is not necessary.